# Ads: How to compromise between annoying users vs. more impressions + determining ad-free cost (mobile app)?

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation, mobile-application

I have a dating mobile app and am having trouble monetizing effectively with ads.

My app uses interstitials, and even rewarded video locks, which I am aware are pretty annoying. How should you decide the cap/timer on how many of these to show, and any other general tips?

Secondly, what's a good price for an ad-free experience? I believe I may be charging too much right now cause I get very little purchases, despite a good amount of users, and some pretty annoying ads...

I'm aware this depends on the app really, and how much people like it, but I think any general advice would help me with how unsatisfactory things have been. In general, they seem to really kill the UX without paying much at all (using Google AdMob and Facebook Audience Network).

Answer (score 2):

You will find many articles on web on this topic, but here is what I think will help you:

**Engage users with their interests**

Upon the first launch of your app ask users about their interests and use them to display related news in intervals paired with Ads - your users may not mind the interruption.

**With Quotes - one liners**
In general, users do like to read motivating small quotes of their interest. Make user of it, also provide and option to share the quote on their social networks.

**Referral Fee**
Get into partnership with other apps that share share similar customer base - integrate their offerings in your app and earn as referral fee. But you have to be cautious about the kind of partners you choose.... make sure they are trustworthy.

**Give Trials**
In order to get people to buy paid version you have to let them experience the luxury for some time. It's a proven stratergy - once people know the best of paid version some of them will prefer buying it.

You mentioned your app is using interstitials - try avoiding it, because it has become the annoying feature. [Death-to-app-install-interstitials](https://techcrunch.com/2015/09/01/death-to-app-install-interstitials/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way that I came across to earn good money via monetization of app was to let the users decide how much they want to pay you.

You can bring a popup once a day with title "Support Me"

The content be something like this :)

[image]

You can watch this shot on : https://dribbble.com/shots/2069852-Support-us-Page

Comment: You say this is 'one of the best ways' to monetize an app. Why do you say this? Certainly it is an option to go with, but have you any evidence that it really works? What makes you say 'best' here?

Comment: I saw this method in an app few years ago... and then I implemented it in one of my app... and guess what people actually donated more. Here you give a reason that this money matters to you a lot